# Git merge excluding todo comments

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I would like to be able to see a list of todos in a branch by doing git diff between that branch and my master branch. but If I merge commits from that branch then I'll need to remove those comments in master and commit again. Is there a way to do that in one command.

Comment: To merge a branch into `master`, is just join the latest commit from the branch into `master`. If you don't need changes about todo comments included, you can create a `temp` branch, then use `git rebas -i`  to remove the commit about todo, then merge the new created branch `temp` into `master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply list ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24212372/6309)) the branches which are *not yet* merged to master:

```
git branch --no-merged master | cut -c3- | while read branch; do
  git grep 'TODO' "$branch"
  # or
  git diff master..$branch | grep "^+.*TODO"
done
```

See [`git branch --no-merged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---no-mergedltcommitgt).